# TypeError: Cannot Read function of 'fetch' of undefined (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, fetch

> Ok so basically its showing me an Error that property of fetch dosent exist i am using the replit database for a balance command (discord.js)
> [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df5ss.png)

Here is the command file:

```
const { match } = require("../functions.js")
const Database = require("@replit/database")
const ms = require('pretty-ms')
const db = new Database()
module.exports = {
  name: 'balance',
  description: 'ping cmd',
  permissions: [],
  aliases: ['bal'],
  async execute(client, message, args, Discord) {
    let user = message.mentions.users.first() ||
  client.users.cache.get(args[0]) ||
  match(args.join(" ").toLowerCase(), message.guild) || 
  message.author;

  let bal = await client.db.fetch(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}.pocket`);
  if (bal === null) bal = 0;

  let bank = await client.db.fetch(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}.bank`);
  if (bank === null) bank = 0;

  let TotalMoney = bank + bal;

  let moneyEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor("#FFFFFF")
  .setDescription(`**${user}'s Balance**\n
  **Pocket:** ${bal}
  **Bank:** ${bank}
  **Total:** ${TotalMoney}`);
  message.channel.send(moneyEmbed)
    }
}
```

So how do I fix the error

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well client.db does not exist, this is what your error message is telling you. I am suggesting you to read the docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/@replit/database

The fix:

```js
let bal = await db.get(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}.pocket`);
```